# Woocommerce - My account menu items not showing proper content

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i would like to ask a question about woocommerce my account functionality. I have access to "My Account" and also access to menu items like /orders etc..., but when I come to for example /orders it is showing me the same content like on the dashboard (welcome message)

What is wrong? I tried to disable modules, but seems not to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have set up those pages. If not you can create them. On install Woo automatically create those pages if not you can tell WooCommerce what pages to use. Cehc official documents.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-pages/

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply! I came throught It and did not found anything what should be wrong, so i just clicked on save settings, and i do not know how, but it works, thank you